# Reverting a complex merge

Tags: git

We have a bit of a mess where an old branch had subsequent work done
that was all merged down to a dev branch, but with other work done in dev in between
so:

we started with dev
then branched off to 5.6.9
work continued on dev, but also on 5.6.9
all work on 5.6.9 was merged down into dev
a branch was created off the latest in dev (by this stage ~1800 commits ahead of 5.6.9) and then merged into 5.6.9 - which is what we want to revert

we dont have a linear history we could revert back to a given commit because of the work done on 5.6.9 in between commits on dev, and cant find any way to find a commit hash for the merge as the log of the old branch now contains all of dev (ie git log --merges shows all the feature branches merged in to dev, not the merge into 5.6.9 that we did)

Is there a record git keeps of all merges?  And any way to tell it to undo a merge (that has been pushed)?

Comment: Yes, git knows about all merges... they are commits with more than one parent.  You can see the merges on a branch with `git log --merges`.  `git revert` can be used to revert a specific commit.  But you may want to read up on it.  Here's a [nice post](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html) on undoing merges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a

```
git log --grep Merge
```

To get your commitid.

And then:

```
git rebase --onto <commit-id>^ <commit-id> HEAD
```

That should deal with it.

Comment: I tried this, and git log --merges but it has all the merges into dev, rather than a single merge into 5.6.9 that would undo all the 1800 commits it brought in.  sure I'm missing something but struggling to find what

Comment: didnt solve the issue - in the end we had to a reset --hard HEAD~2 back on the developers machine who did the merge - but think this is because of a helper they used that had a push --force in (and yep, that no longer exists as know the perils of rewriting history!)

Answer (score 0):

For the merge commit you could just grep it in the git log as suggested by sjakubowski i.e.

`git log --grep Merge`

Then once you found the merge commit you can revert it by

`git revert -m 1 <merge_commit_id>`

This should work.